# Fitting an array of formulas to the frame

Tags: beamer, math-mode

i have drawn   a picture with the following  code :

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}c@{}l@{}}
\toprule
 \hat{A}  &&  \hat{B}  \\
 (a,A=g^a)  &&  (b,B=g^b)  \\
  x\in_R[1,q-1] ,\quad  X=g^{H_1(x,a)}   \\
& \xrightarrow{\textstyle  X } \\
&&  y\in_R [1,q-1] ,\quad  Y=g^{H_1(y,b)}  \\ 
& \xleftarrow {\textstyle  Y } \\
  K=H_2(Y^a,B^{H_1(x,a)},Y^{H_1(x,a)},\hat{A},\hat{B})  \\
&&  K=H_2(A^{H_1(y,b)},X^b,X^{H_1(y,b)},\hat{A},\hat{B})   \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it likes this [image] Can someone help me to adjust it to frame? thanks

it appears again....

```
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
\toprule
\hat{A}&&\hat{B}  \\
(a,A=g^a)&&(b,B=g^b)  \\
  x\in_R\mathbb{Z}_q ,X=g^{H_1(x,a)} \\
\delta_{\hat{A}}=SIG.Sign(a,\hat{B}\parallel\hat{A}\parallel X)  \\
&\xrightarrow{\displaystyle (\hat{B},\hat{A},X,\delta_{\hat{A}})} \\

&& Verify  X\in \mathbb{Z}_q    \\
&&SIG.Verify(A,\delta_{\hat{A}},\hat{B}\parallel\hat{A}\parallel X) \\
&& y\in_R \mathbb{Z}_q , Y=g^{H_1(y,b)}  \\ 
&& \delta_{\hat{B}}=SIG.Sign(b,\hat{A}\parallel\hat{B}\parallel X \parallel   \delta_{\hat{A}} \parallel Y) \\
& \xleftarrow {\displaystyle (\hat{A},\hat{B},X,Y,\delta_{\hat{B}}) } \\
&&  K=H(X^y) \\
Verify Y\in\mathbb{Z}_q \\
SIG.Verify(B,\delta_{\hat{B}},\hat{A}\parallel\hat{B}\parallel X \parallel \delta_{\hat{A}} \parallel Y) \\
 K=H(Y^x) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
```

like this [image]  i really don't know why?

Comment: You may add `\footnotesize` at the beginning of your frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really reconsider doing this because not only it looks very ugly but also doesn't convey much of a message in terms of mapping back and forth. But here is a fit

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}}
 \hat{A}  &&  \hat{B}  \\
 (a,A=g^a)  &&  (b,B=g^b)  \\
  x\in_R[1,q-1] &&   \\
  X=g^{H_1(x,a)} &&\\
& \xrightarrow{\displaystyle  X } \\
&&  y\in_R [1,q-1],\\
&&Y=g^{H_1(y,b)}\\
& \xleftarrow {\displaystyle  Y } \\
K=H_2(Y^a,B^{H_1(x,a)},Y^{H_1(x,a)},\hat{A},\hat{B})  \\
&=&H_2(A^{H_1(y,b)},X^b,X^{H_1(y,b)},\hat{A},\hat{B})   \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i've got another example but it appears the problem i give in the picture again ,i don't  know why  please help me

Comment: @Alex It's not a problem. You are filling up the frame with excessive amount of material and the paper area is limited. You have to find another way to convey your message.

Comment: it's not in the middle of frame, as you can see. always a little to the right. why?how can i adjust this ?

Comment: @Alex it starts from the left margin but it doesn't fit so it overflows the page. Either use smaller fonts or remove stuff. There is no other way.